# What are my options when I want to restructure mediawiki content

Tags: mediawiki

I have a bunch of articles written on the mediawiki. Some of the articles are too long and complex, and are good candidates for splitting up so some chapters will form a distinct articles.

OTOH some articles are too small and too similar to be stored separately - I'd like to join them together into one meta-article, containing contents of the smaller ones as chapters.

I can do it with manually by copying & pasting source for each article. It is doable, but I'll need to manually promote/demote heading levels on pasted articles. And also I will need to deal manually with links, that will inevitably get broken.

Since mediawiki is so mature I guess there must be more a more efficient way of managing its content. But I can't google it up. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no specific tool to do what you ask for — or, rather, manually copying and pasting the text *is* the tool for that.

However, there are some features in MediaWiki that can help with some of the issues you list, particularly link breakage:

- When you merge a stand-alone page into another as a section, you can replace the original page with a [section redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aRedirect#Section_redirects) like this:

  ```
  #REDIRECT [[New combined page#Section heading]]
  ```

  That way, anyone following a link to the original page will be automatically sent to the correct section on the new page.
- When you rename a section, any existing direct links to that section will stop working.  (They'll just take you to the top of the page, since the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) no longer exists on the page.)

  However, as a workaround, you can introduce an explicit identifier into the page using the HTML `id` attribute; these are most conveniently placed on an empty `span` or `div` just before the section you want the link to lead to, like this:

  ```
  <div id="Old section title" />
  == New section title ==
  ```

  You can also use this trick to include abbreviated identifiers for sections with long titles, or even to allow section-style linking to any arbitrary position on a page.
- Finally, if you want to split sections of a long page into separate pages, it's often convenient to leave a summary page at the original location, with links to all the new pages.  If you retain the section structure of the original page, but just reduce each section to a brief summary (+ a link to the full text on another page), even old section links will continue to work.

  Wikipedia uses this technique extensively: most Wikipedia articles on large general topics are written in [summary style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aSummary_style) (of which the page I linked to is itself an example), with short (often single-paragraph) sections starting with a link to a more detailed article, like this:

  ```
  == Subtopic X ==

  : ''Main article: [[Subtopic X]]''

  A very brief description of subtopic X as it relates to the main topic
  of the page...
  ```

  (Except that they actually normally use [a template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aMain) for the "main article" link.)

Also, if you do find yourself needing to manually edit pages to fix link targets, there are some third-party tools like [AutoWikiBrowser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aAutoWikiBrowser) that can be useful.  In particular, the AWB [Disambig tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aAutoWikiBrowser/User_manual#Disambig) could be useful in retargeting links to a split page.  While it's designed for fixing links to [Wikipedia disambiguation pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDisambiguation), I don't see any reason why it couldn't handle your use case just as well.